# Any way of setting the background color to a user defined image using swing?

Tags: java, swing

So,

I have a component that listens to user input and draws an image from the last place the user clicked on to the next place he clicks on.

That is simple enough.

The issue is that I need to display this on a presentation and I would just love to change the background of this user defined image to avoid giving the impression that I just left the default colours because I am lazy.

I have defined a colour scheme with light gray/ default that kinda works around the issue(the application I am displaying is quite more complex than this but this is my only issue) but I would just love to have more freedom when it comes to background colours.

This class is in charge of storing the user input

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
/**
* Component that takes user input
*/
public class UserDefinedImage extends JComponent {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image image;

private Graphics2D g2;
private static Integer  oldX, oldY,tempX,tempY;
public UserDefinedImage() {
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            if (g2 != null) {
                g2.setPaint(Color.black);
                // draw line if g2 context not null    
                if(oldX==null){
                    oldX=e.getX();      
                }  
                if(oldY==null){
                    oldY=e.getY();

                }  

                else{
                    tempX=e.getX();
                    tempY=e.getY();
                    g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, tempX, tempY);

                    oldX=tempX;
                    oldY=tempY;

                }
            }

            // refresh draw area to repaint
            repaint();


        }



    });
}


protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
        // image to draw null ==> we create
        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        // enable antialiasing
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    }

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}

}
```

Here is my main window containing a UserDefinedImage panel

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Main {

private JFrame frame;
private UserDefinedImage drawing;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Main() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(222, 184, 135));
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    drawing= new UserDefinedImage();
    drawing.setBounds(0, 0, 428, 244);
    //not working
    drawing.setBackground(new Color(250, 235, 215));
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawing);

}

}
```

TLDR: I have a component that takes user input and Swing can't give it a background in the same way as everything else. 
I get why swing can't give it a background without overriding user input.

I am after setting the background to a colour when initializing UserDefinedImage and then letting the user define the lines it wants to draw and draw over the initially loaded background.

Comment: I am aware that leaving some test code that shows the tests I have been doing.  As this issue depends on user input I have opted for adding a TLDR to explain the issue to anyone who does not have the time to go over the whole code.

Comment: *"I get why swing can't give it a background without overriding user input."* Ummmm .. good? I really don't understand what you're saying there. As an aside, that's not the only part of your question that's confusing me. You speak of background images and colors as if they were the same. Given they're not, which do you mean?

Comment: I want to set a background color.

Comment: So the title *"Any way of setting the background color to a user defined **image** using swing?"* should read *"Any way of setting the background color to a user defined **color** using swing?"*? Please [edit] the title and question to reflect that the problem is nothing to do with images.

Comment: I want to set a background color. Then let a user draw  over it on a different colour. I'm going to try and see if creating a colored polygon with the dimensions it will have at the beginning works. I just want to avoid having the empty background color on the areas that the user doesn't define lines (most of the picture). I mention picture and background color because I'm after both. I want to generate a picture made up on a series of connected lines(done) and I'd love to achieve a background color on said picture that differs from the empty one(harder than I thought to achieve).

Comment: If it's necessary to see the BG color behind the image, make it a transparent image (e.g. `new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)`).

Comment: That did it. Sorry if I was not making much sense earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's necessary to see the BG color behind the image, make it a *transparent* image.

E.G. instead of:

```
image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
```

Have:

```
image = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
```